# Redirecting é in Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, encoding

I have a number of redirects that are using the é symbol.

have tried replacing the é with \x{009E} in the redirect, and that does not appear to have done it.  Are there any other options?

Example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/tr\x{00E9}s$ http://www.mysite.com/fr/index.html
```

Should redirect /trés

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know whether `\x{009E}` is a valid regular expression. I always write unicode char in this form: `\u5e7f`. All of my reference books said `\x` can only be followed by a 2-digit hexadecimal.

Then, do you have a A HTTP packet sniffer tool (e.g. Firebug or Inspect Element tool of webkit)? 
When testing this URL in my site, I noticed that my browser had encoded the é as `%C3%A9`.

[image: Developer Tools]

So I tried this rule in my personal site, whick worked well.

```
RedirectMatch ^\/tr\xC3\xA9s http://www.mysite.com/fr/index.html
```

It also works for IE:

[image: also works in Internet Explorer]

How the "é" will be encoded completely depends on user's browser and OS (not your server). In my case, I'm using a Windows 7 PC with Chinese language pack.

You should capture the packet by yourself to decide what code to replace `\xC3\xA9`.